# Python- Unable to forward HID data though TCP/IP Connection

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm a bit new to python and am having a rough time with this. Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to share HID device data between user accounts when multiple users are logged in at once. 
The Python script below should start a TCP/Server on 127.0.0.1, collect the HID device data and then send it out the TCP connection. I have another python script listening on 127.0.0.1 and printing the received data.

The script below collects, and prints, the HID data correctly but fails to send it though the TCP connection. If I run a seperate script that just creates the TCP connection and writes plain text, using the same method as below; the listening program picks it up correctly. Think it might be something small I'm overlooking, I tend to overthink things.

```
import sys
import socket

hid = { 4: 'a', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: 'f', 10: 'g', 11: 'h', 12: 'i', 13: 'j', 14: 'k', 15: 'l', 16: 'm', 17: 'n', 18: 'o', 19: 'p', 20: 'q', 21: 'r', 22: 's', 23: 't', 24: 'u', 25: 'v', 26: 'w', 27: 'x', 28: 'y', 29: 'z', 30: '1', 31: '2', 32: '3', 33: '4', 34: '5', 35: '6', 36: '7', 37: '8', 38: '9', 39: '0', 44: ' ', 45: '-', 46: '=', 47: '[', 48: ']', 49: '\\', 51: ';' , 52: '\'', 53: '~', 54: ',', 55: '.', 56: '/'  }
hid2 = { 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'D', 8: 'E', 9: 'F', 10: 'G', 11: 'H', 12: 'I', 13: 'J', 14: 'K', 15: 'L', 16: 'M', 17: 'N', 18: 'O', 19: 'P', 20: 'Q', 21: 'R', 22: 'S', 23: 'T', 24: 'U', 25: 'V', 26: 'W', 27: 'X', 28: 'Y', 29: 'Z', 30: '!', 31: '@', 32: '#', 33: '$', 34: '%', 35: '^', 36: '&', 37: '*', 38: '(', 39: ')', 44: ' ', 45: '_', 46: '+', 47: '{', 48: '}', 49: '|', 51: ':' , 52: '"', 53: '~', 54: '<', 55: '>', 56: '?'  }
fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')

ss = ""
shift = False
done = False

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 44004
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

while not done:
    buffer = fp.read(8)
    for c in buffer:
        if ord(c) > 0:
            if int(ord(c)) == 40:
                done = True
                break;
            if shift:
                if int(ord(c)) == 2:
                    shift = True
                else:
                    ss += hid2[ int(ord(c)) ]
                    shift = False
            else:
                if int(ord(c)) == 2 :
                    shift = True
                else:
                    ss += hid[ int(ord(c)) ]

print(ss)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
sock.send(ss)
sock.close()
```

Data sent with this script is picked up correctly by the listening program.

```
import socket
import sys

obj= sys.argv[1]

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 44004
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(obj)
s.close()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _fails to send it though the TCP connection_?  Does `sock.send()` throw an error?

Comment: @JohnGordon It prints the correct collected Information, but where it should be sending; nothing comes through on the listening program. No error occured

Comment: If `print(ss)` works as expected, then I don't see how `sock.send(ss)` can just silently fail.  Can you show us the separate script you mentioned that does work as expected?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm not understanding that myself. I added the script above.

Comment: In the second script, the type of `obj` is clearly a string.  What type is `ss`?

Comment: When I declared it I set it to an empty string; so it should be a string. I know in python you don't have to declare the specific variable type.

Comment: _When I declared it I set it to an empty string; so it should be a string_ You reassign `s` at a few points in the loop, so there's no guarantee that it's still a string when it finally gets sent.

Comment: @JohnGordon it is being concatenated with a string value base of positioning in the `hid` and `hid2` arrays. When its printed, before its sent, the value that is printed is '!1234567890?'. I don't get what else the compiler would think it is.